# CKAN creates a default sysadmin user with ckan run command

Tags: admin, ckan, system-administration

CKAN creates a `default` user when it starts the development server.

```
ckan -c /etc/ckan/production.ini run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

If the the default user is deleted and ckan is restarted again, it appears again. I don't want to have a default sysadmin user since I have my own admin user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `site_user` is created on startup and its used only for internal services. If it gets removed it will be recreated on every `get_site_user` call